# Is there a way for someone to post a question thread that would be a list of the various “Star Wars” Death Star plans backstories on the site?

Tags: discussion

[I just posted a question about *Star Wars* (1977)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/what-did-darth-vader-mean-by-there-ll-be-no-one-to-stop-us-this-time-who-had) and inferred at one point near the end of that question that *Rogue One* (2016) was not the first attempt to give some depth to the backstory of how Rebels acquired the Death Star plans.

[In my comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/what-did-darth-vader-mean-by-there-ll-be-no-one-to-stop-us-this-time-who-had#comment384996_149775) I provided links to two online sources of details on past attempts to flesh out the backstory of *Star Wars* (1977): Information [on the 1981 NPR radio drama](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)) as well as [more info on various books/media that touch on the backstory of the Death Star plans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_star_plans).

So that said, is there *any* proper way of presenting these disparate sources into something interesting, more fleshed out than the Wikia pages that would be able to latch onto the interest in *Rogue One* as well as providing the Internet with some depth to the topic?

I mean, it is interesting to dive into this stuff. But creating a “list request” is a known no-no here, right?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking. Do you want to ask a question, write an answer, or both?

Comment: If there are only a few different versions of how the Death Star plans were stolen, the question “How many different versions of the theft of the Death Star plans are there?” would probably be fine.

Comment: [That question already exists.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124400/51226)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Possibly

**Not *all* list questions are disallowed.** As noted [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/51379), the main issue is with open-ended lists, which tend to be too broad and to accumulate single-item "me too" answers:

> It’s not reasonable to ask a question on a Q&A site that requires
>   knowledge of all works that ever existed, and then request a massive
>   list of the works that contain one specific element. This sort of
>   question lacks a single, finite answer. In practice these questions
>   accumulate a steady flow of “me, too” answers where people add a few
>   examples in a new answer.

And similarly, as noted in the [consensus answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10399/51379) to a newer question:

> By themselves, “long” list questions from a specific small domain
>   aren’t necessarily a problem; unless a specific question attracts
>   1-item answers instead of a comprehensive list.

A list with a short, finite scope, such as the list of all (Legends and canon) Star Wars backstories for the theft of the Death Star plans, *could* be on-topic. But it depends on how it’s asked, and what sort of answers it’s seeking. **A question that asks for a *full summary* of even a *single* account of how the Death Star plans were stolen (e.g. *Rogue One*) could be too broad**, and it seems like you might be suggesting that sort of question, based on wanting something “more fleshed out than the wiki pages.”

**On the other hand, a question like “How many different versions are there of the theft of the Death Star plans?” would probably be perfectly fine.** There shouldn’t be more than a handful, so it would be a nice, finite list. But a good answer to this question wouldn’t necessarily contain a full summary of each novel, radio drama, and movie that detailed the theft of the Death Star plans.

If you really want to write a point-by-point summary and comparison of the various stories of how the Rebels acquired the plans, on the other hand, there might be a place for that on the [blog](http://thesffblog.com/), which allows for long-form writing free of many of the restrictions of the Q&A format.

Comment: @JakeGould - if you are really looking for a succinct list of all references to the Death Star plans in tie-in materials - then really the main / most used resource of record is Wookiepedia - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_plans/Legends - in which case, I think a question asking for something like that alone would possibly fall under general reference - http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/689/what-sites-should-be-considered-general-references/ - wondering what Adamant thinks